# Take values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$carousel = array(
    array(
        "cite" => 'title_1',
        "blockquote" => 'description_1',
        "imgs" => 4
    ),
        array(
        "cite" => 'title_2',
        "blockquote" => 'description_2',
        "imgs" => 2
    )
);
```

I want to wrap this infos in html and echo n images as the imgs value.
I only be able to echo n images but i want to associate cites and blockquotes separately.

I tried to use foreach but with no success:

```
foreach ($carousel as $images){
    foreach ($images as $key => $value){
        echo $value . "\n";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $value; $i++) {
            echo("image url" . "\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I obtain all the values when I echo $value and images:

```
title_1
description_1
4
image url
image url
image url
image url

title_2
description_2
2
image url
image url
```

but I want to use them separately like this

```
<cite>title_1</cite>
<blockquote>description_1</blockquote>
<img></img> //4 times as specified in "imgs"
<img></img>
<img></img>
<img></img>

<cite>title_2</cite>
<blockquote>description_2</blockquote>
<img></img> //2 times as specified in "imgs"
<img></img>
```

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Use a for loop by reading the value of imgs and casting it as int.

Comment: Well you could start the process by echoing an `<img>` tag rather than a text string!!!!

Comment: But your BIG probelm is that you do not have anthing resembling an URL To an images file and location

Comment: There is no image urls in your array. Post real data instead so that we get something to work with

Comment: I don't understand why all these downvotes. I miss something... Please can you explain this? Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra foreach loop that you do not need.

Try this:

```
//loop through array
foreach($carousel as $values) {

    //echo cite info
    echo "<cite>{$values['cite']}</cite>";

    //echo blockquote info
    echo "<blockquote>{$values['blockquote']}</blockquote>";

    //loop until you have the same amount of <img> tags as defined in the `imgs` array element.
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $values['imgs']; $x++) {
        echo "<img></img>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works. The following is the complete code with image references as asked by @RiggsFolly: foreach($carousel as $values){$return = '<li> <div class="text"> <cite>' . $values['title'] . '</cite><blockquote>' . $values['blockquote'] . '</blockquote> </div> <div class="image">'; for ($x = 1; $x <= $values['imgs']; $x++) { $return .= '**<img src="' . $path . 'img/gallery/' . $values['title'] . '-' . $x . '.jpg"></img>**'; } $return .= '</div> </li>'; echo $return; }

Comment: @pitinca Glad that I could help.